# Better method to prevent users from changing data attributes in developer tools?

Tags: php, ajax, validation, security, attributes

I am trying to find an efficient way of preventing the users from changing data attributes in a form. I need it as I use those values when making queries, and It wouldn't be great if a user changed a data-id atrribute, and the query would delete a completely different record.

I have a table called 'groups' and am listing groups from it to HTML. A data attribute holds the group id, and users can delete groups through the UI. What I have done so far is the following:

I do not display the actual group id in the html, instead I generate a random string (substring of a hash value) and that is what I insert in the data attribute as the value. Then, I create a session variable, that hold an array in which I store all the group IDs and the displayed random strings: the random string is the key, and the actual ID is the value. Later, when the AJAX call is sent, I check if the data attribute value is exists amongst the array keys, and if not, I reject the request as the random string was modified. Otherwise the key exists, and I get the value associated with it.

Here's code so far:

```
<?php
    $groups = $user->getGroupsByAuthor();
    foreach($groups as $group):
    $group_id = generateGroupId();
    $_SESSION['listed-group-ids'][$group_id] = $group['id'];
?>
<li>
    <div class="group-image" style="background-image: url('uploads/<?php echo $group['image'] ?>')"></div>
    <h4><?php echo $group['name'] ?></h4>
    <small><?php echo $group['description'] ?></small>
    <span class="btn-delete-group" data-group-id="<?php echo $group_id ?>"><i class="ion-close"></i></span>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And in the parser file, I check if the key exists:

```
    if( empty($_SESSION['listed-group-ids'][$_POST['group-id']]) ){
        exit('Do not try to modify values!');
    }

    delete the record from database...
```

Can it be a good way or it is unefficient? Any other experiences or methods you do? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can assign data values with javascript and they don't show up in the html

Comment: Short answer is you can't outright prevent it so you need to code defensively to account for invalid data no matter how good your preventative tools are to limit modification in the first place. In that respect assume you are going to get people messing with the data, how do you handle that?

Comment: @Danny What do you mean by “people messing with the data”? Every time a user changes a value in devtools, no matter what that user types in as a modified value, the request is going to be invalid, isn’t it? ( not arguing, just curious )